# SAML SSO integration for third party app inside asp.net mvc web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml, idp

> We have an existing SAAS asp.net MVC web application hosted in-premise
> and using custom forms authentication for user credentials, means users credentials are stored in our sql database. Now we
> plan to integrate with a 3rd party crm and wants to integrate their
> solution inside our using SSO. They supports SAML based SSO and
> supports Azure AD SSO. We are going to be integrate with other 3rd
> party solutions using SSO in near future too which may be using OpenId
> connect or SAML.
>
> As we are identity provider here so in order to integrate with many
> service provider for SSO is it necessary that we need to use Azure AD
> or similar solution for identity provider (IDP) or is there any other
> way too. Also as we are hosted in-premise so in case to integrate with
> SAML based Azure AD SSO do we need to host of azure?

Answer (score -1):

It need not be Azure AD alone but any IDP provider which you would zero in on per your technical and business requirement.
And once you have zeroed in on the IDP, it can be used for all the applications that support SAML authentication mechanism.

Comment: As I wrote it can be SAML or OpenId+Oauth too so I am looking for something which can be used for both of these SSO solutions. Also in order to make it happen inside a asp.net mvc application is it necessary to reply on 3rd part or we can design our too by using Identity server 4 etc.